# c# mobgoDBDriver update - Using Projections

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Recently I make an update from Mongo c# driver (MONGODB .NET DRIVER) from version 1.8.x to 2.4.4. The goal is to use projections that are not supported in older version (1.8). The update was made using nuget.

[Installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCryE.png)

The problem is that the syntax like:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("status", "A");
var projection = 
Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("item").Include("status");
var result = collection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).Project(projection).ToList();
```

the find method still stands for a IMongoQuery type and not a FilterDefinition, what I believe is for compatibility reasons.

But the question is whether is possible to use projections making this kind of update, or I will need to undo the upgrade, remove 1.8 version, install version 2.4.4 and fix all incompatibilities from scratch?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I would like to help but can you try to specify your goal more precisely?

Comment: looks that because compatibility issues, for the fact that I made an update through nuget, it created the MongoDb.Driver.Legacy, and I cannot use the projections available in this driver version.... This is my suspect, but not sure...

Comment: Because you installed mongocsharpdriver you have MongoDb.Driver.Legacy. Try removing just that nuget package. 3 packages you need are mongoDb.BSON, mongoDB.Driver and mongoDB.Driver.Core